# Is this Rock-a-My Soul 5-string banjo tablature for one instrument or two?

Tags: practice, tablature, banjo

What does this 5-string banjo tablature represent? I took this to be for a single banjo where notes such as those above the labels A and C are pinches. However, that doesn't make sense at the note labeled N where the fingering is 0 and 1, both on string 2.

Now I'm wondering if this is actually for two banjos, one playing the melody tab and the second playing the roll tab.

What's actually supposed to be done?

My thinking is that it's supposed to be two instruments. For the purposes of my studying efforts, I intend to record the melody track along with metronome, then play along with that, doing the roll tab. Then, do the opposite for practicing the melody.[image]

Comment: That looks like two instruments, especially given that the second string is played both open and fretted at the first fret on the "-bra-" of "A-bra-ham".

Comment: @DavidBowling, thanks, that what I'm thinking, but I have minimal knowledge so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece appears to be arranged for two banjos, but it could also be performed by one person singing the top line and playing the bottom line. That's probably why they included the lyrics. Your plan to record it both parts is great practice, though.